How to decide which chunking technique to use for implementing Retrieval-Augmented Generation(RAG)
I want to automatically generate testcases using generative AI. For this purpose I will be using open source LLM (Llama 3, will try others as well). Since the LLM is trained only on publically available data, it needs more information regarding the application being developed (for which I wish to generate testcases) and the requirements which contain detailed information regarding the expected behaviour.
This additional information can be provided through RAG. The Vector Database being used is ChromaDB.
As of now, I want this additional information to be provided as a PDF file.
According to my researched, there are many ways of dividing this PDF file into smaller chunks:

Recursive Character Splitter
Sentence splitter
Semantic splitting
LLM based chunking
Document specific splitting

Please do let me know if I missed some other useful method.
So there are 2 questions here:

How to decide which chunking method to choose?
How can I evaluate the performance of the chosen chunking technique?

